# Scripts are blocked: 404 and "you must enable javascript" noscript tag when js is enabled. Page loads when I disable javascript or open in incognito

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

This is a .NET core 3.1 app with a lot of Jquery. This issue appears when you open the deployed site in a browser for the first time, only a blank page appears. Previously I have fixed this issue by simply clearing my cookies and cache, but I do not want to require my users to reset their browsers to use my site. I have also added `asp-append-version="true"` to my script tags but this did not fix my issue. On Chrome on my android device, this issue is fixed by blocking javascript for this site, and broken again by re-enabling javascript, which I do not understand at all. Is there a way to fix this without requiring people to reset their browsers?

[image: Console with scripts enabled]

[image: Elements with scripts enabled]

Comment: Your question doesn't contain enough information. it's not clear what requests are 404'ing, nor where in your client code these requests originate from. However, if your problem is resolved when you clear your cache, it's probably not an actual issue. Most likely you made code changes on the server side (in your C#), and corresponding changes in the JS. If you reload without clearing the cache, you might receive the *old* JS, which makes requests the server is no longer expecting. You (and anyone using your site) need to clear the cache and refresh, in that case. There is no way to avoid this.

Comment: @R.Davidson - The requests that are 404ing are the initial loads of script tags containing my javascript (jquery, signalR, etc) that are shown to not be loading in the first image. These script tags exist at the bottom of my layouts page like this "<script src="~/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>". This problem occurs the FIRST TIME you visit the site, so it is not possible for old static files to be cached.